Caching previous values in solve_ivp
I want to use the temperature at the previous timestep when evaluating the next timestep. I don't want to use global, because I think it slows down the code and it is not very clean.
I use scipy.integrate.solve_ivp to solve the mass balance, and I have an if statement in the function that checks if the concentration exceeds a limit. When the upper limit is exceeded the temperature changes and it has to keep this temperature until the concentration exceeds a lower limit then it has to change back to the original temperature, and so on. Because I use the temperature in the function during a calculation, it has to use the temperature of the last timestep. I fixed this by making the temperature T global, but I am looking for a better solution.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
time_check10 = True
T_outside = 20

def mass_balance(t, y):
    c = y[:len(y)//2]
    q = y[len(y)//2:]

    global T

    if t == 0:
        T = T_outside
    else:
        pass

    dc_dt = np.zeros_like(c)
    dq_dt = np.zeros_like(q)
    dc_dz = np.zeros_like(c)
    q_eq = np.zeros_like(q)

    # Boundary conditions inlet
    dc_dz[0] = (c[0] - c_feed) / dz
    # Boundary conditions outlet
    dc_dz[-1] = 0
   
    # Discretization in z-direction
    dc_dz[1:-1] = (c[1:-1] - c[:-2]) / dz
    
    # The complete mass balance equations
    dq_dt = (q_eq - q) * K * T

    dc_dt = (-u * dc_dz / epsilon) + (-((1 - epsilon) / epsilon) * rho * dq_dt)

    if q[-1] >= q_lim_outside:
        T = T_inside
    elif q[-1] <= q_lim_inside:
        T = T_outside
    else:
        pass
    
    global time_check10
    if time_check10 == True and t > 0.1*Time:
        print('10% completed after', round(time.time()-start_script,1), 'seconds')
        time_check10 = False

    return np.concatenate((dc_dt, dq_dt))

sol = solve_ivp(mass_balance, t_span, y_initial, t_eval=t_eval, method=method, max_step=dt, dense_output=False)

Making the temperature T global in the function currently works. I tried passing T via args in solve_ivp and updating that, but I didn't get it to work how I wanted.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please provide enough code so we can copy and paste it and run it.

I recently saw a different answer that shows how to do this, but I can't remember which answer that was (I will update this with the reference if I ever find it again).
What you can do is exploit how python deals with default mutable arguments in a function (this is discussed here). In brief, if you have a mutable default argument, such as a list, then that list will be created on the first function call and will persist, including changes, in all future calls. For example:
def f(times_called=[0]):
    times_called[0] += 1
    print(f"This function has been called {times_called[0]} time(s)")

for i in range(10):
    f()

Output:
This function has been called 1 time(s)
This function has been called 2 time(s)
This function has been called 3 time(s)
This function has been called 4 time(s)
This function has been called 5 time(s)
This function has been called 6 time(s)
This function has been called 7 time(s)
This function has been called 8 time(s)
This function has been called 9 time(s)
This function has been called 10 time(s)

The times_called variable is updated each time the function is called and you didn't have to deal with global variables.
So, here's a similar example to what you want:
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def ode(t, y, y_prev=[None]):
    if t == 0:
        y_prev[0] = 0
    dydt = -y_prev[0]*y      # -y_previous*y_current
    y_prev[0] = y
    return dydt

sol = solve_ivp(ode, [0, 10], [1])

The main "difficulty" here is setting a variable initial value for y_prev. One way you might be able to handle that is to use functools.partial to fill in a y_prev0 argument.
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from functools import partial

def ode(t, y, y_prev0, y_prev=[None]):
    if t == 0:
        y_prev[0] = y_prev0
    dydt = -y_prev[0]*y      # -y_previous*y_current
    y_prev[0] = y
    return dydt

y_prev0 = 0
ode_partial = partial(ode, y_prev0=y_prev0)

sol = solve_ivp(ode_partial, [0, 10], [1])


thanks for your reaction, I didn't manage to make it work in this way unfortunately. Did you find the other solution where you were speaking about?

I haven't found that other answer, but they had suggested this exact thing. You should update your question with a simple and complete example so I can actually test what you've tried.
